# Javascript incrementing by more than one

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, increment

```js
var x1 = document.getElementById("x1");    
var x2 = document.getElementById("x2");

function ThisEvent(){// needs a lot of work done to it
  if (x1.value==1) {
    x2.value--;
  } else if (x1.value==2) {
    x2.value++;
  } else if (x1.value==3) {
    x2.value+=5;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="0" id="x1" onblur="ThisEvent()"> x1     </br>   
<input type="text" value="0" id="x2"> x2
```

what is happening now is the digit is being added instead of incrementing when 3 is the input if x1. how do you make it increment by more than just one, without it being added it as a digit?

Comment: Not certain what expected result is?

Comment: Hint: it's not a number but a string.

Comment: espected result is if one enters 1 in x1, x2 decreases by 1. if one enters 3 in x1, x2 increases by 5 without adding 5 as a new diget

Comment: Does any of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (x1.value == 3) {
    x2.value = parseInt(x2.value) + 5;
}
```

It's interpreting it as a string. You can `parseInt` the `x2.value` in the calculation.

Comment: i use parseInt and it fails

Comment: disregard it worked wonders. thank youvery much @Bitwise Creative

Answer (score 0):

The value of the input is a *String*, you need to convert it to a *Number* in order to perfom an addition on it.

You could do it like this:

```
function ThisEvent() { // needs a lot of work done to it
    var valX1 = Number(x1.value);
    var valX2 = Number(x2.value);
    if (valX1 == 1) {
        valX2--;
    } else {
        if (valX1 == 2) {
            valX2++;
        } else {
            if (valX1 == 3) {
                valX2 += 5;
            }
        }
    }
    x2.value = valX2;
}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v1utqv7f/